# JAXB Unmarshalling works on one server but not the other

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have an application that I run locally and on our demo server.  When I run the code locally it can take an XML response and unmarshal it into a `Response` Object, just as one would expect.

When I run that code on our demo server (EXACT same code) unmarshalling produces a `null` result.

I've looked and made sure that both servers are configured the same and they're both getting the same response XML.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: It is possible you are getting a different jaxb provider in your 2 different environments. Search for "how to specify a particular jaxb implementation"

Comment: It is possible.  I did check the context however and do see that it "knows about" the classes it's unmarshalling.

Comment: Have you found your solution?  Today (2016-12-24) I had a similar problem and I posted about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308531/jaxb-unmarshalling-failed-on-one-machine-but-not-others-also-worked-in-unit-te  If you have some insight please share with us.  Thanks!  Happy Holidays!

Comment: @leeyuiwah, looks like you found your answer.  I had the exact same issue of multiple versions of the same class being loaded by my classloader.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You might be using *org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller* to unmarshall XML response  into a Response Object in your local environment(Windows). But the same code when you are running in server(which could be either unix or linux environment) fails to unmarshall  and produces a null result.

So instead of *org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller* use *org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller* to unmarshall which is able to unmarshall in all the different environments.

https://programmingproblemsandsolutions.blogspot.com/2019/03/jaxb-unmarshalling-works-locallywindows.html